# Learning how to model a person

Tags: mesh

What is the best platform/website/youtube channel to learn how to animate a pixar style 3d animated human character (useing mesh not sch

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this video for the types of modeling

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-CvkAm9CYA

To start straight away with character Darenlile video is a good source

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT1GNMevfc